# UIButtons don't respond to touch after set frame on autorotate

Tags: iphone, interface, uibutton, rotation

Hello in my app i have some uiButtons added as subviews to a view like in the picture below.
[alt text http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/5244/portraitc.png](http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/5244/portraitc.png)

when the user rotates the phone in landscape the views and buttons must change position to this:
[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5931/landscapeq.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/5931/landscapeq.png)

initially when the view is in portrait mode the buttons respond to touches. If i tilt the phone the buttons move, everything looks ok like in the second image and the buttons respond to touches. If i tilt the phone back to portrait mode, the buttons move back they look ok but they don't respond to touches. If i change back to landscape the buttons work...

my buttons are created like this:

```
nextNewsP = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 40, 10, 25, 25)];
[nextNewsP setImage:[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"next_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextNewsP addTarget:self action:@selector(nextNewsAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nextNewsP setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
[bottomTools addSubview:nextNewsP];
[nextNewsP release];

previousNewsP = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 85, 10, 25, 25)];
[previousNewsP setImage:[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"previous_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[previousNewsP addTarget:self action:@selector(previousNewsAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[previousNewsP setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
[bottomTools addSubview:previousNewsP];
[previousNewsP release];
```

bottomTools is a view and is added also as a subview like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:bottomTools];
[bottomTools release];
```

and my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation function looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveViews" context: nil];


    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"set frames for portrait");
        closeView.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 30, 2, 23, 25);
        newsInfo.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 10, 22);
        internetActivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 55, 5, 18, 18);
        industryLabel.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2.0 - [industryTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]].width/2, 3, [industryTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]].width, 22);
        bottomTools.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-40, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 40);
        nextNewsP.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 40, 10, 25, 25);
        previousNewsP.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 85, 10, 25, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"set frames for landscape");
        closeView.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 30, 2, 23, 25);
        newsInfo.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 10, 22);
        internetActivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 55, 5, 18, 18);
        industryLabel.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2.0 - [industryTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]].width/2, 3, [industryTitle sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]].width, 22);
        bottomTools.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-40, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, 40);
        nextNewsP.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 40, 10, 25, 25);
        previousNewsP.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 85, 10, 25, 25);
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

return YES;
```

}

did you ever had a similar problem? 
thank you in advance, 
Sorin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in your frame adjustment.  My gut tells me it has something to do with the logic being inside `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` because that happens before the rotation is actually done.  Try doing your math the way they do it in [this article](http://blog.sallarp.com/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation/) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll try it and return with a feedback. Sorin

Answer (score 1):

I am actually still struggling with the same problem (a year later ... need iOS 3.0 compatibility). The rotation part was easy. However, the views and buttons don't seem to process touch and move/drag events. I've verified that the window (UIWindow) is receiving the touch events and at the right locations.

It's as if the last 1/3 of the screen (i.e. 480-320) doesn't propagate events to receivers after a rotation to landscape from portrait.

The example in the link by slf doesn't help since the rotated view controller doesn't have responders.

---

I just figured it out after some view digging. So, I was rotating the viewController.view and doing a bunch of setNeedsLayout on subviews of viewController.view. However, what I needed to do was [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]. That one call fixed everything for me. For whatever reason, the navigationController.view wasn't passing touch events to the part of the subviews that were previously hidden (as far as the frame/bound is concerned). That actually fixed a number of other issues as well.

Comment: check to see if views aren't overlapping or if they have user interaction enabled. these come into my mind currently.

Comment: Na, it's not that. I just figured it out after some view digging. So, I was rotating the viewController.view and doing a bunch of setNeedsLayout on subviews of viewController.view. However, what I needed to do was [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]. That one call fixed everything for me. For whatever reason, the navigationController.view wasn't passing touch events to the part of the subviews that were previously hidden (as far as the frame/bound is concerned). That actually fixed a number of other issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem I was having .. I basically needed to do `[self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout]`.

The way I understand this (which maybe incorrect is that `self.navigationController.view.frame` was same as `self.view.frame` and both were equal to (x=0,y=0,width=320,height=480). I then rotated `self.view` by `M_PI/2` and did a number of frame manipulation on select self.view.subviews to get everything to animate/position/scale correctly.

That worked out okay but the navigation controller was not willing to acknowledge touch events to parts of self.view there were to the right of 320. In essence, if this `self.navigationController.view.clipsToBounds` were true, it might not even have shown that part of self.view.

Anyway, setting setNeedsLayout on the navigation controller's view resolved the issue. I hope this helps someone else. I suspect that was also the problem SorinA was having with buttons not getting touch events.

Comment: This is my solution to my own problem posted below.